# In .NET MAUI, how do I get a Stream or Write to a file with a URI that was from user-picked file?

Tags: android, .net, stream, filesystems, maui

In MAUI, I have `SaveFileAsync` method that has a `Stream` (the content) to be written to a file picked by user. I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file) so user can pick a file and the result is a Java `Uri`.

Now from that Uri, I have no idea how to make a Stream from it. This is my attempt so far but it doesn't work.

```cs
    public partial async Task SaveFileAsync(string name, Stream stream)
    {
        const int SaveFileCode = 300;

        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
        intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
        intent.SetType("application/pdf");
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, name);

        var (resCode, data) = await ActivityResultService.Instance.StartActivityForResultAsync(intent, SaveFileCode);
        if (resCode != Android.App.Result.Ok || data is null) { return; }

        var path = data.Data?.Path;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(path);

        using var outStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        await stream.CopyToAsync(outStream);
    }
```

The exception is:

> Could not find a part of the path '/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf'.

My current workaround is to use Java API instead of .NET. Is there a way to create a Stream to an Android URI so I can read/write a file?

---

Working solution using `OpenOutputStream` from `ContentResolver`:

```cs
    public partial async Task SaveFileAsync(string name, Stream stream)
    {
        const int SaveFileCode = 300;

        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
        intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
        intent.SetType("application/pdf");
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, name);

        var (resCode, data) = await ActivityResultService.Instance.StartActivityForResultAsync(intent, SaveFileCode);
        if (resCode != Android.App.Result.Ok || data is null) { return; }

        var uri = data.Data;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(uri);

        var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(activity?.ContentResolver);

        using var outStream = activity.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(uri);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(outStream);

        await stream.CopyToAsync(outStream);
    }
```

Comment: you obviously should use content resolver and open stream from uri as usi is not a path

Comment: @Selvin thank you. So that's the Java API I was talking about. I can get `FileOutputStream` (`Java.IO`). So do I have to stick with Java API from there on, or is there anyway to switch to .NET Stream?

Comment: `ContentResolver.OpenOutput(Input)Stream` seems to return dotnet `Stream` in xamarin sdk API - but I don't know how it applies to MAUI

Comment: @Selvin You are correct! That solves my problem. I will add my finished code and you can put it in an answer and I will mark it :)